# cant start docker after installation on linux

Tags: linux, docker

hy 
On my CentOS Linux release 6.0 with kernel version 3.15.7-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64, i've installed docker like that

```
yum install docker-io  it's ok
```

but when i try to start docker i get this

```
 /etc/init.d/docker start  
Starting docker:                                           [  OK  ]
```

in the log file i see this

```
[5b73ca03] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
[5b73ca03] +job initserver()
[5b73ca03.initserver()] Creating server
2014/07/30 13:52:24 Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
exit status 1
[5b73ca03] -job initserver() = ERR (1)
2014/07/30 13:52:25 exit status 1
```

i really dont understand why i get -job initserver() = ERR (1) i read a lot of tutorial for install docker on centos, i also try to add in fstab " none  /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults 0 0 "
when i try grep aufs /proc/filesystems  i see nothing that normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for resolve my problem  i use nsenter

https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

And i use this script for have a automatic connection on the contenair i've only one contenair up !

```
#!/bin/bash 
CONTAINER_ID=`docker ps --no-trunc | sed -n 2p | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1`
PID=`docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' $CONTAINER_ID`
nsenter -m -u -n -i -p -t $PID /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out and then back in again first.

Comment: i try to restart my computer 2 times but i get the same error

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear.  Try the steps found partway down the page at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/CVhHPJzY_A8

Comment: i read and try everything what he say but i get the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

i get this reponse from unclejack on github
That setup is unsupported. Please upgrade to RHEL7 if you want to use a newer kernel than what CentOS 6 ships.